# subscripting with 2 arguments in python

Tags: python, subscript-operator

Assume I have a class X which has 2 attributes : i and j.

I want to have :

```
x = X((1,2,3),(2,3,4)) #this would set i to (1,2,3) and j to (2,3,4)
```

I now want subscripting to work in the following way :

```
a, b = x[1,2] #a should now be 2 and b should now be 3
```

At the moment I'm trying this :

```
    def __getitem__(self, i, j):
        return self.x[i] , self.y[j]
```

However this keeps giving me the error that **getitem** takes in exactly 3 arguments but 2 is given (when I try to print out x[1,2] for instance)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comma is the tuple packing operator. `x[1, 2]` calls `x.__getitem__((1, 2))`.

```
def __getitem__(self, ij):
   i, j = ij
   return self.x[i], self.y[j]
```

Comment: wow, that was quick..Could you give me a pointer to where this is explained in more detail?

Comment: @ArnabDatta: `T *ptr = &internet;`. Seriously, though, I'd imagine tuples are explained in any Python tutorial.

Comment: call me a noob, but I tried searching the internet for __getitem__ with multiple params, subscripting with multiple params, and looked through explanations of the getitem method without any luck. 
The fact that comma is the tuple packing operator is not obvious to someone new to python, so the sarcasm isnt exactly well recieved in this case.

Comment: @ArnabDatta - tuple packing and unpacking isn't specific to `__getitem__` and is described somewhat here:  http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Comment: @ArnabDatta: This is not related to `__getitem__`. `__getitem__` takes an object (as in `x[obj]` is equivalent to `x.__getitem__(obj)`), you pass a tuple here (I'm pretty sure the official tutorial remarks that it's comma that creates a tuple, not parenthesis). There's nothing more to it. Also, joke and sarcasm is not the same thing.

Comment: still, the Python language reference defines object.__getitem__(self, key) as required for a class to implement a container object, and "key" is a single argument.  The fact that x[1,2] results in key being set to a tuple (1,2) requires some reading between the lines, since without knowing the answer in advance getting from the __getitem__() definition to tuple is a bit of a leap.  Thanks for making the implicit explicit.